# find the value of a column that is next to the max value in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, max, where-clause

I am struggling with a problem. I have a pandas df that contains X,Y coordinates from different players. I can get the max X-coordinate value of the row with `.max(axis = 1)`.

What I hoping to achieve is to make a new column that contains the value that's next to the max value. That is, how do I find the adjacent value of the max X-coordinate column. So it would be the Y-coordinate that's next to the Max X-coordinate for any given row.

Note: There will never to duplicate max values.

See below for example.

```
df
Player 1_X  Player 1_Y  Player 2_X  Player 2_Y  Player 3_X  Player 3_Y
6           7           5           8           **9**       3
5           7           6           7           **8**       2
4           6           **7**       7             6         1
```

Intended df:

```
df1
Player 1_X  Player 1_Y  Player 2_X  Player 2_Y  Player 3_X  Player 3_Y New Column 
6           7           5           8           9           3          3
5           7           4           7           8           2          2
4           7           5           7           6           1          7
```

I have tried an if statement and where function but don't know were to begin as I'm new to python.

Comment: What is your question and what have you done so far to answer it?

Comment: Do you mean the question isn't clear? I have tried to run an if statement and a where function. I can do it in excel but need to run this over a large dataset

Comment: It's not like the question isn't clear. I see no question whatsoever.

Comment: Did you read the submission. I have a pandas data frame. I need to return the value of the column that's next to the MAX X coordinate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What don't you understand about the question. 1) I have a pd df that contains X,Y coordinates. I would like to return the value of a column that is next to the max value of the X-coordinate.

Comment: There is no question in your post. A question starts with "how", "why", etc., and ends with a question mark. What I see is a problem and a man who wants us to write him some code and refuses to cooperate. SO is not a code writing service. If you are new to Python, you should first master Python and then mess up with pandas.

Comment: I've adjusted the question. I was trying to keep the question as clear as possible. I can provide more context of what I've done thus far if adequate info isn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way, thought it might not be the most efficient:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['Player '+str(x)+'_'+y for x in range(1, 4) for y in ('X', 'Y')]
x_cols = ['Player '+str(x)+'_X' for x in range(1, 4)]

df = pd.DataFrame([[6, 7, 5, 8, 9, 3],
                   [5, 7, 6, 7, 8, 2],
                   [4, 6, 7, 7, 6, 1]],
                  columns=cols)

df['usecol'] = df[x_cols].idxmax(axis=1).apply(lambda x: cols[cols.index(x)+1])
df['New Column'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x['usecol']], axis=1)
df = df.drop('usecol', 1)
```

Comment: Thanks jp. Works well.